# Reference request: good reduction equivalent to crystalline étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, etale-cohomology, p-adic-hodge-theory

Suppose $X$ is an abelian variety over a $p$-adic field $K$, and it's well known that $X$ has good reduction is equivalent to the étale cohomology of $X$ is crystalline, and $X$ has semistable reduction equivalent to semistable étale cohomology. I wonder is there a good reference (with proof) for these two things?

Comment: Coleman-Iovita.

Comment: @Satan'sMinion Could you provide the title of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Satan's Minion says, the good reduction case is

R. Coleman, A. Iovita, *The Frobenius and monodromy operators for curves and abelian varieties*, Duke Math. J. 97 (1999), 171--215.

For the semistable reduction case, see

C. Breuil, *Groupes $p$-divisibles, groupes finis et modules filtrés*. Ann. of Math. (2) 152 (2000), no.2, 489–549.

Comment: Note there seem to be two versions of the former paper online: one turns up publicly available on Google, but seems to be less complete than the other version.